# combine two select queries with one commonl column but with different results

Tags: sql

I'm struggling to combine these two sql queries to obtain a table with just 3 columns

```
SELECT M.name, COUNT(A.MusicianID) AS AlbumAppearance
        FROM Album A, Musician M
  WHERE A.MusicianID=M.MusicianID
     GROUP BY M.name
  

  SELECT M.Name,COUNT (Pr.MusicianID)  AS SongAppearance  
        FROM  Performs Pr, Musician M
  WHERE Pr.MusicianID=M.MusicianID
  GROUP BY M.name
```

Comment: Please add sample data, expected result and only use tags for the DBMS you are using

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you provide some data about the table and what you have tried

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your source data and what you expect as a result?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming musician names are unique (which seems like a very reasonable assumption), correlated subqueries are probably the simplest and best performance way to do what you want:

```
SELECT m.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Album A
        WHERE A.MusicianID = M.MusicianID
       ) as AlbumAppearance,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Performs Pr
        WHERE Pr.MusicianID = M.MusicianID
       ) as SongAppearance
FROM Musician m;
```